# Solve a set of modular equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can someone give a hint to me about this problem? :/ This is so hard for me:
 
Find the total number of solutions to the following system of equations:
$a^2+bc \equiv a \pmod{37}$
$ba+bd \equiv b \pmod{37}$
$ca+cd \equiv c \pmod{37}$
$bc+d^2 \equiv d \pmod{37}$
$ad-bc \equiv 1 \pmod{37}$

Comment: $bc$ appears three times, I'd probably start playing with combining formulas to eliminate that, eg. $a^2-d^2\equiv a-d \bmod 37$

Comment: I just thought of something. Maybe the last one is about matrix determinant?

Comment: The first four equations correspond to solving for matrix $M$: $M^2=M\pmod{37}$

Comment: @IanMiller And the last one says it's invertible. So, we have an invertible, idempotent matrix. That sounds like something there cannot be too many of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we let $M = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ be a matrix with $\Bbb Z$ modulo $37$-entries, then the first four equations say that $M^2 = M$, and the last equation says that $M$ has determinant $1$, and hence is invertible.

Since $M^{-1}$ exists, we may apply it to the equation $M^2 = M$, and we get $M = I$. Thus $a = d = 1$ and $b = c = 0$.

Comment: +1 Yes, that is a much neater solution. Unfortunately, I only saw your comment after I had slogged through prosaically!

Answer (score 2):

All working below is mod 37.

The second equation is $b(a+d-1)=0$, so either $b=0$ or $a+d=1$.

Case 1. $a+d=1$. Since $ad=1+bc$ and $bc=a-a^2$ we have $a(1-a)=1+a-a^2$ or $1=0$, which is false. So we cannot have $a+d=1$.

Case 2. $a+d\ne1$. So $b=0$. Similarly from the 3rd equation in the question, $c=0$. Hence $a=a^2$ or $a(a-1)=0$, so $a=0$ or $a=1$. Similarly, $d=0$ or $d=1$. But $ad=1+bc=1$, so $a=d=1$.

Answer (score 1):

So we have, all $\pmod {37}$:
$$\begin{align}
a^2+bc &\equiv a  \tag{1}\\
ba+bd &\equiv b   \tag{2}\\
ca+cd &\equiv c  \tag{3}\\
bc+d^2 &\equiv d  \tag{4}\\
ad-bc &\equiv 1  \tag{5} \\
\\
a^2 + 2ad +d^2 &\equiv a+d+2  \tag{from 1+4+5+5}\\
(a+d)^2  &\equiv a+d+2  \tag{6}\\
\end{align}
$$

From $(2), b\equiv 0$ or $(a+d)\equiv 1$ and from $(3), c\equiv 0$ or $(a+d)\equiv 1$.

However from $(6)$ it is clear that $(a+d) \not \equiv 1$ since $1^2 \not\equiv 3$ so $(b\equiv 0, c\equiv 0)$.

Then from $(5), ad\equiv 1$ so $a,d\not\equiv 0$. Then from $(1), a^2 \equiv a \implies a\equiv 1$ and thus also $d\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- The given system is equivalent in the field $\mathbb F_{37}$ to
$$a(a-1)+bc=0\\b(a+d-1)=0\\c(a+d-1)=0\\bc+d(d-1)=0\\ad-bc-1=0$$ You have two cases to consider $a+d-1\ne 0$ and $a+d-1=0$.
$$1)\space a+d-1\ne 0 \Rightarrow b=c=0$$
Furthemore $$a(a-1)=0\\d(d-1)=0\\ad=1$$ This imply immediately $$(a,b,c,d)=(1,0,0,1)$$ In other words $(a,b,c,d)=(1+37r,37s,37t,1+37u)$ with $r,s,t,u$ arbitrary integers.

You can try similarly the second case $a+d-1=0$